# finding a method to prove that $19^{20}\equiv 1 \mod 181$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can we prove that $19^{20}\equiv 1 \mod  181$?

Answer (score 6):

$$19^2\equiv 361 \equiv -1 \pmod{181}\implies 19^{20}\equiv (19^2)^{10}\equiv(-1)^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{181}$$